# Finding elements in two lists within certain range

Tags: python

So I have two lists L1 is fomatted like this:

```
L1 = ['12:55:35.87', '12:55:35.70', ...]
L2 = ['12:55:35.53', '12:55:35.30', ...]
```

I am trying to find pairs in both list that start with the same 4 characters i.e. 
xx:x and then return the indexes of the pairs for each list

So far I have:

```
for pair1 in L1:
    for pair2 in L2:
        if pair1[:4] in pair2:
            print(L1.index(pair1))
```

This doesn't seem to return the correct indexes and it obviously doesn't return the index of the second list. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what are `ra_1` and `ra1`?

Comment: Are these times or other data which can be stored numerically?

Comment: if statement should be if pair1[:4] == pair2[:4]. Also there's a much more efficient way to solve this problem.

Comment: Apologies I fixed the ra_1 stuff

Comment: Do you have any more examples? All first 4 digits occur in all of these strings. Do you only want the *first* index?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how to make your code work. Keep in mind this is a naive solution, there are faster way to solve this if your lists are big. Runtime here is O(n^2) but this could be solved in linear time.

```
for i,pair1 in enumerate(L1):
    for j,pair2 in enumerate(L2):
        if pair1[:4] == pair2[:4]:
            print("list1: %s , list2: %s" % (i,j))
```

Update: for future visitors here's an average linear time solution:

```
from collections import defaultdict
l1_map = defaultdict([])

for i,val in enumerate(L1):
    prefix = val[:4]
    l1_map[prefix].append(i)


for j,val in enumerate(L2):
     prefix = val[:4]
     for l1 in l1_map[prefix]:
        print("list1: %s , list2: %s" % (l1,j))
```

Comment: How do you solve this in linear time? Don't you have to check every pairwise combination?

Comment: O(n^2) should be fine and this worked a treat. Thanks!

Comment: We can sort both lists, and then we get O(n logn), but I'm also curious about linear. Well, dd:d is limited, so we could use a table with 1000 entries.

Comment: @gidim, man, this question was an arms race!  You beat us to the punch though, have an upvote!

Comment: @ArndtJonasson added linear time solution

Comment: @gidim it is still O(n^2) in the worst case scenario tho (when len(l1_map) == len(L1)) no?.

Comment: @rodgdor in that case it will be O(len(L1)+len(L2)) which is still linear. The for loops are not nested.

Comment: @gidim True, my bad.

Answer (score 3):

Because OP lists seem to have lots of repeated "firsts 4 characters", I would do something like the following:

```
indices = {}
for i, entry in enumerate(L1):
    indices.setdefault(entry[:4], [])
    indices[entry[:4]].append("L1-{}".format(i))
    if L2[i][:4] in indices:
        indices[L2[i][:4]].append("L2-{}".format(i))
```

Then you can access your repeated entries as:

```
for key in indices:
    print(key, indices[key])
```

This is better than O(n^2).

**edit**: as someone pointed out in the comments this is assuming that the lists do share the same length.

In case they don't, assume `L2` is larger than `L1`, then after doing the above you can do:

```
for j, entry in enumerate(L2[i+1:]):
    indices.setdefault(entry[:4], [])
    indices[entry[:4]].append("L2-{}".format(j))
```

If `L2` is shorter than `L1` just change the variables names in the code shown.

Comment: This is assuming that both lists have the same length

Comment: @OluwafemiSule True that, it is easy to fix tho, see edit (still faster than O(n^2)).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to loop the Cartesian product.

```
from itertools import product

L1 = ['12:55:35.87', '12:55:35.70']
L2 = ['12:55:35.53', '12:45:35.30']

res = [(i, j) for (i, x), (j, y) in 
       product(enumerate(L1), enumerate(L2)) 
       if x[:4] == y[:4]]

# [(0, 0), (1, 0)]
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem in the question, he asked for a list of pairs of indexs rather then pairs of the elements themselves.

Comment: Nice, upvoted!  However, I would argue that maybe a list comprehension hurts the readability at that point?

Comment: Yeh, maybe, I've split it across 3 lines. Seems readable to me now, but may not be to everyone's liking.

Comment: It's also possible I'm just not great at understanding list comprehensions at a glance & it's actually fine. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

Use the `range()` or `enumerate()` function in the for-loops to provide you loop index.

For example, using the `range()` function:

```
for x in range(len(L1)):
   for y in range(len(L2)):
       if L1[x][:4] == L2[y][:4]:
           print(x, y)
```

Comment: So many similar answers so close together, nice job!  Have an upvote!

Answer (score 1):

enumerate is great for things like this.

```
indexes = []
for index1, pair1 in enumerate(L1):
    pair1_slice = pair1[:4] 
    for index2, pair2 in enumerate(L2):        
        if pair1_slice == pair2[:4]:
            indexes.append([index1, index2])
            print(index1, index2)
```

Comment: Neat, you only perform the slice `len(L1)` times!

Answer (score 1):

I think the [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function is what you're looking for!

```
L1 = ['12:55:35.87', '12:55:35.70', 'spam']
L2 = ['12:55:35.53', 'eggs', '12:55:35.30']

idxs = []

for idx1, pair1 in enumerate(L1):
    for idx2, pair2 in enumerate(L2):
        if pair1[:4] == pair2[:4]:
            idxs.append((idx1, idx2))

print(idxs)
```

Output

```
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2)]
```